# "OpenSSL version is too old" while compiling http 2.4.16 on MacOS 10.11

Tags: apache, openssl, osx-elcapitan

I encounter an error with OpenSSL while compiling http 2.4.16 on El Capitan 10.11.1.

It is looking for OpenSSL version >= **0.9.8a**:

```
checking for OpenSSL... checking for user-provided OpenSSL base directory... none
checking for OpenSSL version >= 0.9.8a... FAILED
configure: WARNING: OpenSSL version is too old
```

The default OpenSSL version is **0.9.8zg**:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
```

And finally here is a part of my compilation line:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/MyWebserver/httpd-2.4.12 \
--enable-ssl \
--with-few-things… \
--disable-lots-of-things…
```

I don't want to install another openssl even with `brew`.

Comment: The configure command worked when I fixed the variable `ac_cv_openssl=yes` at line 24800 in the configure file.

but then an error occurred during the make:
    `fatal error: 'openssl/rsa.h' file not found`

Comment: The compilation works on 10.9 an 10.10 even though the openssl version is identical so I guess something different comes from the new system…

Answer (score 5):

For me, the problem was solved by installing the package 'openssl-devel'.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

I resolved it by telling "configure" which open-ssl to use:

When doing ./configure, please add the following:

> --with-ssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2r

whereas, 1.0.2r is your current version of openssl, usually installed by brew.

I prefer doing this method rather than messing about with the system files (i.e. don't like to link anything on /usr/... directories as it messes up with the system, especially Apple will always do an update to prevent you from doing this), therefore, the following command works:

> ./configure --enable-ssl --enable-so --prefix=/(Wherever you like to
>   install location) --with-included-apr --with-mpm=prefork
>   --with-ssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2r

For my installation to work, I also needed to download the apr and apr-util, unzip and place them onto the srclib folder before installing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. Worked like a charm. However the *make* command says **no targets**, of course it has got nothing to do with openssl

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to copy things if you have a current version of OpenSSL installed (using Homebrew), creating a symlink is sufficient to ensure it is picked up by the configure command:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl /usr/local/include
```

More details: https://medium.com/@timmykko/using-openssl-library-with-macos-sierra-7807cfd47892

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

The openssl being outdated was the result of not having the proper libraries install.

installing libssl via : `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

caused `--enable-ssl` to function without extra configuration

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found a way :

1. Copy the folder /usr/incude/openssl from a Yosemite (MacOS 10.10) to /usr/local/include/openssl on my computer (El Capitan MacOS 10.11).
2. Then compile apache by adding a flag to the compilation environment variables gcc and g++ : -I/usr/local/include

Here are all the variables that I use :

```
ARCH="-arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7"
LDFLAGS="-O3 $ARCH"
CFLAGS="-O3 -fno-common $ARCH"
CXXFLAGS="-O3 -fno-common $ARCH"
CC="gcc $ARCH -I/usr/local/include"
CXX="gcc $ARCH -I/usr/local/include"
CPP="gcc -E"
CXXCPP="g++ -E »
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need to provide the headers.
Download the Openssl source code [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/0.9.x/), and then copy to /usr/local/include/ as below,

```
$ sudo cp -r include/openssl /usr/local/include/
```

then everything will work fine.

Comment: I can't copy it to /usr/lcal/include as I am compiling an application which contains the Webserver in itself (almost like MAMP for example)